# php header download redirect

Tags: php, header

I'm making a file sharing site for the fun. Trying to make it so that when I hit download, it starts the download. Instead of just a link to `/files/$file` im trying to do a header redirect:

**download.php**

```
/**
* File Download
*/

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,desc FROM files WHERE id = ".intval($_GET['id']));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$file = $row['name'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}

?>

Filename: <?=$row['name']?>
Desc: <?=$row['desc']?>

<a href="#">Download this file</a>
```

Im stuck here, what should I do next?

thank you

Comment: Note that "readfile and fpassthru are about 55% slower than doing a loop with feof/echo fread". according to someone on php.net

Comment: @Alex L: Wow, Really? I thought readfile was faster as it could mmap... Have you ever tested this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this, where the page will display the information about the file and then when the user has clicked th link it will download it?

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,desc FROM files WHERE id = ".intval($_GET['id']));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$file = $row['name'];

if(!file_exists($file))
{
    exit('File does not exist');
}

if(intval($_GET['download'])===1)
{
    // Generate the server headers
    if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE"))
    {
        header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    }
    else
    {
        header('Content-Type: "application/octet-stream"');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    }
    $data = readfile($file);
    exit($data);
}
else
{
?>
    Filename: <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
    Desc: <?php echo $row['desc']; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&download=1">Download this file</a>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following what you are asking.  A header redirect looks like:

```
header("Location: /path/to/new/page");
```

If you want the existing info to download, looks like you need to hit it with an id in your url:

```
<a href="file.php?id=<?=$file_id ?>">
```

where `$file_id` has the id of the file you are looking for.  Personally, I'd put that in another file from the page that shows the listing and download link, but YMMV.

Comment: Per RFC 2616 http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30, you should use an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do a redirect before any html has been pushed.

Basically after

```
Filename: <?=$row['name']?>
Desc: <?=$row['desc']?>

<a href="#">Download this file</a>
```

is sent to the browser, your chance to perform a redirect with php is over. Maybe a Javascript redirect is more appropriate? [Tutorial on Javascript redirects.](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php)