# Run PHP on button click and hide download link

Tags: php

With this code I want to turn it into when a user clicks on the button it first verifies that they want to download the file and if they click yes it subtracts 100 points from the $userpoints (and then update the mysql table, but I know how to do this), what I need help with is getting the code to run when someone clicks the button. Also I want to give them the download without them getting a url that they can reuse. Either by not showing them the url or making it a unique one time code.

```
<?php                       
                    //If submit form was clicked
                    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        //Server side validation for security purposes
                        if($userpoints >= 100) {
                            mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET points = points - 100 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
                            $filename = 'ibelongwithyou.mp3';
                            $filepath = '/home4/saintfiv/downloads/';
                            header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
                            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=I Belong With You.mp3");
                            readfile($filepath.$filename);
                        }else {
                            header("Location: index.php?error=1");
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <?php
                        if ($userpoints >= 100) {
                            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts">';
                        } else {
                            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts" disabled title="You need at least 100 points for this download">';
                        }
                        if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 1) {
                            echo "Error, you must have atleast 100points";
                        }
                    ?>
                    </form>
```

With this updated code it seems that it is still registering a click on the submit after refreshing. Also something weird is happening with a bunch of random characters that just keep going down the page.

Comment: I figured out the download part using headers, so the main thing I need help with is how to get it to run when someone clicks on the button

Comment: please include the DOWNLOAD link, for example a path for your download...or if it is BASED to a database table then show me your download table fields

Comment: I updated my code, can you see what is going on, I made a test account so you can see what is happening, saint57records.com/rewards username: test password: test. I only have the code on the first track, when you click on it, it registers subtracting the points in the database but then I don't get the download and all the weird characters appear.

Comment: After looking at it some more I think it is actually printing out the file, but I may be wrong. When I put it outside of this I don't get the same error.

Comment: Yeah it prints out the BINARY of the file, there is something wrong about your code about the header for redirecting to a file
review this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123433/php-header-download-redirect

Comment: I decided I am going to try something different and have it set a variable in the table and then allow users to access the download if the value is true

Comment: well providing them the path of the file is unsecured for your website, its like giving them the full path and if they share the file path anyone could download it...I recommend to explore more about the header content...goodluck

Comment: I found a way that I can give them a one time download link that expires, thanks for you help on how to make it work on submit, however something weird is happening where it requires you to push the submit twice to make it run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not include a Javascript/jQuery to validate the button clicking, its all up to you to include a **client side** validation. Furthermore you must store a session either the **user_id** or **username** of the user for future sql statements like what I did, I assumed that you are using **$_SESSION['user_id']** to find the real user.

```
<?php
session_start();

function getPoints() {
    //you must store the user_id atleast for a session or even the username on how you db really done
    //find the data where the USER_ID is the same as $_SESSION['user_id']
    //then we need to get the 'points' field to pass into a variable $userpoints
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['user_id']);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['points'];
}
//If submit form was clicked
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Server side validation for security purposes
    if(getPoints() >= 100) {
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET points = points - 100 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1");
    }else {
        header("Location: index.php?error=1");
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample Point Downloading</title>
        <script><!-- Javascript here for Validation --></script>
    </head>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <?php
        if (getPoints() >= 100) {
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts">';
        } else {
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="100pts" disabled title="You need at least 100 points for this download">';  
        }
        if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 1) {
            echo "Error, you must have atleast 100points";
        }
        ?>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: yes I am using $_SESSION['user_name'] and assigning it to the variable $username, and what do I need to validate and how exactly would I do that, or if you could at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: if you want to do some pop up validation for browser then we call it **CLIENT SIDE VALIDATION** , by doing that you must know how to use javascript or better to use jQuery [http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)